# Sending SSH command from Windows shortcut

Tags: linux, ssh, windows

I have a shortcut which in the terget field has:

```
"C:\Program Files\PuTTY\putty.exe" user@remoteMachineName -pw password
```

I want to add some commands to send to Linux, so that for example after clicking this shortcut Im logged in automatically (as it is now) and for example 'htop' is launched. How do I do that?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39362794/1997354

Comment: @VlastimilBurián As far as I understand this still dont allow to use non-interactive commands.

Comment: As I do not use Windows for a decade, I do not really remember already what I used back then... and that information would have been deprecated by now anyway. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

`plink.exe`, which is shipped with PuTTY is better suited for this. You can either use it for every single command you want to run, or you put the commands as a script on the server and run the script with `plink`.

Comment: Good answer, didn't know about `plink`.

Comment: `"C:\Program Files\PuTTY\plink.exe" user@remoteMachineName -pw password htop` is not working for me

Comment: Same for `"C:\Program Files\PuTTY\plink.exe" user@remoteMachineName -pw password --no-antispoof -t "htop"`, the window closes immediately.

Comment: Well, that's the point of plink. It's for non-interactive commands.

Comment: Is there any way to launch non-interactive commands?